# python - select from a list of things

Tags: python, python-2.7

First of all, i'm completely noob in python and programming aswell, so i'm just trying to catch something from here and there and improve as much as i can.
I have this piece of code:

```
print ('\n')
country = ''
province = ''
gstTax = 0.05
hrmTax = 0.13
otherTax = gstTax + 0.06
car = 30000.42
shoes = 333.24
laptop = 1000.98

print 'Car added to the basket, price: {0:.2f} $'.format(car)   
print 'Shoes added to the basket, price: {0:.2f} $'.format(shoes)
print 'Laptop added to the basket, price: {0:.2f} $'.format(laptop)
orderTotal = car + shoes + laptop
print ('\n')

country = str(raw_input('Country residence? ')).capitalize()
if country == 'Canada':
    province = str(raw_input('Which province? ')).capitalize()
    if province == 'Alberta':
        print 'Your final payment: ', (orderTotal + gstTax), '$'
    elif province == 'Ontario' or province == 'New Brunswick' \
        or province == 'Nova Scotia':
        print 'Your final payment: ', (orderTotal + hrmTax), '$'
    else:
        print 'Your final payment: ', (orderTotal + otherTax), '$'      
else:
    print 'Your final payment: ', (orderTotal), '$'
print 'Transaction ended, thank you for your purchase'
```

Basically what i would like to add to this is a kind of selection before purchase(i.e: You picked laptop product it costs this much, or you picked 'shoes' product and so on). I know there are lists but i don't know and yet understand them for using. Perhaps maybe someone could point me to the right direction.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is add each item that was added to the basket to an `itemsInBasketList` that way you can loop through, print out the item and add the item price to the order total all in one go. This is type of for loop will go through each item in the list and have item hold a value you can use. Another way (which you probably might be more familiar with) is with indicies. This way you have an index and you access an item of the list at that index and get the value that way. Both accomplish the same thing, one is just easier to write and work with than the other.

```
print ('\n')
country = ''
province = ''
gstTax = 0.05
hrmTax = 0.13
otherTax = gstTax + 0.06
car = 30000.42
shoes = 333.24
laptop = 1000.98
itemsInBasket = []
itemsInBasket.append('Car added to the basket, price: {0:.2f} $'.format(car))
itemsInBasket.append('Shoes added to the basket, price: {0:.2f} $'.format(shoes))
itemsInBasket.append('Laptop added to the basket, price: {0:.2f} $'.format(laptop))

orderTotal = 0
for item in itemsInBasket:
    print item
    if 'Car' in item:
        orderTotal += car
    elif 'Shoes' in item:
        orderTotal += shoes
    elif 'Laptop' in item:
        orderTotal += laptop

country = str(raw_input('Country residence? ')).capitalize()
if country == 'Canada':
    province = str(raw_input('Which province? ')).capitalize()
    if province == 'Alberta':
        print 'Your final payment: ', (orderTotal + gstTax), '$'
    elif province == 'Ontario' or province == 'New Brunswick' \
        or province == 'Nova Scotia':
        print 'Your final payment: ', (orderTotal + hrmTax), '$'
    else:
        print 'Your final payment: ', (orderTotal + otherTax), '$'      
else:
    print 'Your final payment: ', (orderTotal), '$'
print 'Transaction ended, thank you for your purchase'
```